# Dynamically create markers in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm developing an application that loads lots of markers in OpenLayers 3.
However, I would like to dynamically display and load markers while user is panning at a certain zoom level.

Could someone provide me an example, or directions to do that?

For instance, I would like to first create an example that drops a marker where user has clicked on the map.
So, with this information, I will be able to handle the rest and post my solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to create a way for setting this up:

http://weebah.com/weebah_examples/click_to_create.html